# Trying to create a simple switch case that generates a letter grade when the numeric score is entered in Netbean

Tags: java

I'm in an information systems class and know virtually nothing about coding, so please keep answers simple if possible.

I'm trying to create a switch case that allows grades grades 98%+ show an "A+", grades 97%-94% show an "A", and grades 93%-90% show an "A-". So far, only the "A+" works. I'm unsure why the "A" and "A-", as I've written them the exact same way. I've exhausted what little knowledge I have about coding, so I'm hoping to find answers here. My code is posted below.

```
public static void main(String [] args) 
{
    int input, sumAplus, sumA, sumAminus, sumB, sumC, sumD, sumF;
    sumAplus=sumA=sumAminus=sumB=sumC=sumD=sumF=0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
    System.out.println("Please enter you numeric grade [-99 to quit]: ");
    input = sc.nextInt();

    if(input == -99) 
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    while(input != -99)
        {
            switch(input)
            {
                case 100:
                case 99:
                case 98:
               {
                 System.out.println("A+");
                   sumAplus++;
                   break;
               }
               
                case 97: 
                case 96: 
                case 95: 
                case 94: 
                {
                    System.out.println("A");
                    sumA++; 
                    break;
                }
                case 93: 
                case 92: 
                case 91: 
                case 90: 
                {
                    System.out.println("A-");
                    sumAminus++; 
                    break;
                } 
               
            } 

//            if(input>=90)
//            {
//                sumA++;
//                System.out.println(input + "      A");
//      }
//            else if(input >= 70)
//            {
//                sumB++;
//                System.out.println(input + "      B");
//            }
//            else if(input >= 50)
//            {
//                sumC++;
//                System.out.println(input + "      C");
//            }
//            else if(input >= 35)
//            {
//                sumD++;
//                System.out.println(input + "      D");
//            }
//            else
//            {
//                sumF++;
//                System.out.println(input + "      F");
//            }

            System.out.println("Enter another grade [-99 to quit]: ");
            input = sc.nextInt();
        }
        
        System.out.println("The total number of A's is " + sumA );
        System.out.println("The total number of B's is " + sumB );
        System.out.println("The total number of C's is " + sumC );
        System.out.println("The total number of D's is " + sumD );
        System.out.println("The total number of F's is " + sumF );
    } 
}
```

Comment: Confused by your claims. All 3 of `A+`, `A`, and `A-` works fine. You are however only printing the number of A's, ignoring A+ and A-. Perhaps you want `println("The total number of A's is " + (sumAplus + sumA + sumAminus) )`? --- Voting to close as "Not reproducible".

Comment: I agree with @Andreas. Also, do you have to use switch statement? This sounds like it might make more sense with an if statement.

Comment: Hmm that's weird. So, It's saying the "A" and "A-" is working for you? Whenever I enter a score of <=97, it just shows up blank. The total number part of the code hasn't been updated yet. I've just been trying to resolve the issue of the "A" and "A-" not showing up.

Comment: @davidalayachew yes it has to be a switch statement for the homework. it was recently an if statement, but we were supposed to edit it to be a switch statement instead in order to produce the "A+" and "A-".

Comment: See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/baWLBv), which shows that program prints `A-`, `A`, and `A+` just fine.

Comment: Any idea on why it might not be working on Netbean?